# Why is the binary (jaeger) from the archive copied incorrectly when building rpm?

Tags: rpmbuild

Trying to pack jaeger-all-in-one in rpm

source code here:
https://github.com/patsevanton/jaeger-all-in-one-rpm

```
rpm is created - but the copied binary is of a different size.

37M Nov 28 11:14 /root/rpmbuild/BUILD/jaeger-1.8.2-linux-amd64/jaeger-all-in-one

32M Jan 29 10:54 /usr/local/bin/jaeger-all-in-one
```

Why is the binary (jaeger) from the archive copied incorrectly when building rpm?

Answer (score -1):

Need add %global __strip /bin/true to spec file